# How to Add a Facebook Like Button to Tumblr

Tags: facebook, tumblr

There doesn't seem to be any official documentation on Tumblr or Facebook as to how to add a Facebook like button within posts.

The only documentation I see is

- http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Using the second link I can place in an individual post but based on the first link, I can only customize everything in one so I would need to get this HTML5 version

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://myusername.tumblr.com/post/1234567" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

(because Tumblr uses `<!DOCTYPE html>`)

Done dynamically for each post.

Also for the Open Graph tags Tumblr seems to be automatically inserting from server side their own meta tags. So which tags should I be adding from?

Would someone care to explain in detail a fool-proof solution for canonical purposes?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you are asking for a way to integrate facebook like button on all posts dynamically, right ?

You can do that by simply adding this code to your post template

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="{Permalink}" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

{Permalink} will be dynamically replaced with the post link.